# smembers : How is insertion order decided?

Tags: redis

When we insert a member in set using `sadd`, is there a deterministic way in which the data will be inserted?
For example,

```
127.0.0.1:6380> smembers test
1) "hello world"
2) "hello"
3) "hello world 1234212"
4) "hello world 123"

127.0.0.1:6380> sadd test "aman"
(integer) 1

127.0.0.1:6380> smembers test
1) "hello world"
2) "hello"
3) "hello world 1234212"
4) "hello world 123"
5) "aman"

127.0.0.1:6380> sadd test "stack overflow"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6380> smembers test
1) "hello world 1234212"
2) "hello world 123"
3) "hello world"
4) "aman"
5) "stack overflow"
6) "hello"
```

As it can be seem , when I inserted "stack overflow", "hello" is shown in last index instead of index 2 as in previous queries. Is there an explanation for that behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sets are implemented using a hash table and are deterministic. That doesn't mean, however, that the order you get from SMEMBERS is what you'd expect.

If you need lexicographical ordering, use a Sorted Set in which all members have the same score (e.g. zero).

Comment: Do you mean "are not deterministic"? If I use smembers on the same set of members, it will always return the members in one order. So, upon addition of a new member, order may change, things are changing behind the scene, which I am trying to understand.

Comment: I meant deterministic - read about Hash tables to understand how they work, bucket collisions and so forth. Then, keep in mind that Redis also had two different encodings for Hashes (depending on size and config directives, one or the other may be used).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a sorted set, you should use [ZADD](http://redis.io/commands/zadd) to add the items, and [ZRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/zrange) to retrieve them from the set:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd sorted 1 "z"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd sorted 1 "stackoverflow"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd sorted 2 "a"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE sorted 0 -1
1) "stackoverflow"
2) "z"
3) "a"
```

`SADD` and `SMEMBERS` work with unsorted sets.